# Getting limited data from a page which has a Facebook ID

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I just posted a question before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022173/getting-like-data-from-an-url-which-has-a-facebook-id)) and it is working now. But with that question answered, another one came up.

This URL below I have only my shares

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://marceloduende.com/facebook_test/index.html

And on this URL, I have all this data...

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2380247/#lb-vi2114495513

Anyone has any advice on how do I get all this data? It's the only trick I couldn't figure out.

Thank you

Comment: Most of that meta data comes from the page source in the form of `og:`, `fb:`, and other tags.  Load the IMDB page and View Source.  You'll see the metadata like `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="115109575169727"/>`

Comment: The page I have has the same metadata, it's actually more organized. http://marceloduende.com/facebook_test/index.html any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The IMDB uses it's own javascript to do the fql and then spit the json. The proof is below. So by default, what facebook provides is what I already have. Thank you all.

Adulterated facebook script:

(function(d,s,id){var js,stags=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if(d.getElementById(id)){return;}js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;
js.src="http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/plugins/rating/js/rating.min.js";
stags.parentNode.insertBefore(js,stags);})(document,'script','imdb-rating-api');

Unminified script version:

http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/plugins/rating/js/rating.js